# Prefab`ы в Unity. Появление в случайном месте

Tags: c#, unity3d, prefabs

Перешарил поисковые запросы, всё то да ни то.

Закидываю в массив префабы для генерации уровня.
После беру случайный префаб из массива и создаю Clone на сцене. Всё бы ничего, но создал я его в canvas, а появляется он просто в пространстве.

Забавный факт в том, что я до этого делал, то же самое, но появилась ошибка в другом месте проекта и я с дуру удалил префабы и скрипты.

**Метод для появления префаба**

```
void LoadPrefab()
    { 
        //sourse - класс для хранения данных, arrayPrefabs массив префабов с нужными префабами
        sourse.numberPrefab = Random.Range(0, arrayPrefabs.Length - 1);

        prefab = Instantiate(arrayPrefabs[sourse.numberPrefab]);



    }
```

**Иерархия префаба**

[image: Иерархия префаба]

**Префаб и его размеры**

Ситуация, когда вне игры перенёс префаб в canvas

[image: Ситуация, когда вне игры перенёс префаб в canvas]

Ситуация, когда создал clone префаба на сцене

[image: Ситуация, когда создал clone префаба на сцене]

Ситуация, когда я ручками его перенёс во время отладки в canvas 1

[image: Ситуация, когда я ручками его перенёс во время отладки в canvas 1]

Ситуация, когда я ручками его перенёс во время отладки в canvas 2 (отдаление)

[image: Ситуация, когда я ручками его перенёс во время отладки в canvas 2 (отдаление)]

Comment: ну скидывай локейшн до нуля после инициализации. В чем конкретно проблема?

Comment: @Andrew При появлении у него ещё и размеры меняются и Scale. плюсом так как он не на canvas его не видно. Я перехожу в режим сцена, ручками перетаскиваю его в canvas и вуаля его видно, но он уже другого размера. Если я в не игрового режима перетаскиваю в canvas, то всё ок. Я сейчас скриншоты накидаю в исправленную статью

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Было бы круто если бы кто-то сказал как это происходит. Почему раньше норм создавались клоны, а сейчас через пидигий

**Что я сделал чтобы они появлялись там где нужно:**

- Подредачил Prefab потому что размеры и scale поменялись на непойми что
- Добавил строчки, которые определяют родителя для моего GameObject
- Ну и поменял значение Scale на 1, 1, 1, то есть размеры как у бати (Parent)
  **Теперь код:**
  (Перетащил canvas в инспекторе)

  ```
      private GameObject prefab;          //Текущий префаб
      public Transform canvas;            //Батя для префаба
  ```

(Поменял положение префаба)

```
        LoadPrefab();                   //При загрузке сцены слонируем случайны из списка префаб
        prefab.transform.SetParent(canvas, true);
        prefab.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1,1,1);
```

Comment: В дальнейшем ещё возникла проблема с местом появления.
Если у вас координаты объекта в каком-то месте делаем:
prefab.transform.localposition = new Vector3(0,0,0); //Координаты центра канваса, вы можете поставить свои